# Issue with priority based LinkedList insertion

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is the basic class: `Issue(priority, description)`
I have a linked list implementation as follows:

```
public class IssueQueue {
    public Issue issue;
    public IssueQueue next;

    private static int count = 0;

    public IssueQueue() {
    }

    public IssueQueue(Issue i) {
      issue = i;
      next = null;
    }

  public int getCount() {
      return count;
  }

  public void Add(Issue newIssue) {
      IssueQueue tempQ = this;
      IssueQueue newIssueQ = new IssueQueue(newIssue);
      if (count == 0) {
          issue = newIssue;
      } else if (issue.getPriority() > newIssue.getPriority()) {
          while (tempQ.next != null
                  && tempQ.issue.getPriority() >   newIssue.getPriority()) {
              tempQ = tempQ.next;
          }

        newIssueQ.next = tempQ.next;
        tempQ.next = newIssueQ;
    } else if (issue.getPriority() <= newIssue.getPriority()) {
        newIssueQ.issue = issue;
        newIssueQ.next = next;
        issue = newIssue;
        next = newIssueQ;

    }
    count++;
}

public void print() {
    IssueQueue tempQ = this;
    if (next == null) {
        System.out.println(issue);
    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println(tempQ.issue);
            tempQ = tempQ.next;
        } while (tempQ.next != null);
        System.out.println(tempQ.issue);
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------");
  }
}
```

The problem is, on doing the following:
    iq.Add(new Issue(10, "Issue 1"));
        iq.print();

```
    iq.Add(new Issue(4, "Issue 2"));
    iq.print();

    iq.Add(new Issue(20, "Issue 3"));
    iq.print();

    iq.Add(new Issue(2, "Issue 4"));
    iq.print();

    iq.Add(new Issue(12, "Issue 5"));
    iq.print();
```

The output is correct till 4th insertion:

```
Issue[Priority: 20, Description: Issue 3]
Issue[Priority: 10, Description: Issue 1]
Issue[Priority: 4, Description: Issue 2]
Issue[Priority: 2, Description: Issue 4]
```

But on 5th Insertion it becomes:

```
Issue[Priority: 20, Description: Issue 3]
Issue[Priority: 10, Description: Issue 1]
Issue[Priority: 12, Description: Issue 5]
Issue[Priority: 4, Description: Issue 2]
Issue[Priority: 2, Description: Issue 4]
```

### Where is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use `Collections.sort()` with your own priority-based `compareTo()` ?

You're essentially asking us to step your code with a debugger. But this looks weird

```
 newIssueQ.next = tempQ.next;
 tempQ.next = newIssueQ;
```

Look you're not even checking against all priorities. I understand this traverses the list but... try stepping in a debugger and you will see.

```
else if (issue.getPriority() > newIssue.getPriority()) {
          while (tempQ.next != null
                  && tempQ.issue.getPriority() >   newIssue.getPriority()) {
              tempQ = tempQ.next;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this code you are inserting the new issue after an issue with a lower priority.

```
while (tempQ.next != null
              && tempQ.issue.getPriority() >   newIssue.getPriority()) {
    tempQ = tempQ.next;
}

newIssueQ.next = tempQ.next;
tempQ.next = newIssueQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the queue from the control logic. Then you won't get confused from the fact you need to think inside out. I'm sure then you'll easily get the bug.

If you can't follow your code in mind -> refactor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write

```
 PriorityQueue<Issue> issues =  new PriorityQueue<Issue>();
```

And implement Class Issue with Comparable.